# Facebook deprecate "offline_access".. and now?

Tags: facebook, api

Well, i'm using the PHP Facebook API to login to my site. Now, I'm use this steps and codes to make the connection:

1. Get the authorized url, and redirect user.
2. Get the code paramns from url by _GET
3. Make api call and get the request access_token

Save into database the access_token and use them in future calls.

This text it from facebook developpers's blog:

> Server-side OAuth Developers
>
> If the access_token is generated from a server-side OAuth call, the resulting access_token >will have the longer expiration time. If the call is made while there is still a valid >access_token for that user, the returned access_token from this second call may be the >same or may have changed, but in either case the expiration time will have been reset. >Again, calling this multiple times during the same day will result only in the first call >extending the expiration time.

Basically, I'm going to do the same steps or I'm confused?
How I extends an existing access_token?

Thanks for all!

Comment: I think Facebook is doing that for you. It will give you a token with extended expiration time, either a new one, or the refreshed old one.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on:

> Save into database the access_token and use them in future calls.

I mean, if the purpose of using Facebook APIs is to authenticate users then no need for the `offline_access` at all!

Once the user *logins* with their Facebook account:

- create a session (refer to the [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/) main class)
- make your API calls
- use the [JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to always check for the user login status to enhance the experience.
- you better save the user Facebook id, name and (maybe) email.
- if you want to save the `access_token`, then the next time the user visit your website and clicks on login button (if not logged to Facebook) **or** the JS-SDK detects that he is a returning user, update your stored `access_token` with the new one!
- Always [handle](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) the expired `access_token`s